# Async callback running before DOMContentLoaded on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I have been doing some experiments to understand the [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).
While experimenting, I came across an interesting difference between Firefox and Chrome (on Ubuntu).

I have this HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        console.log('script is running');

        document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            console.log('DOM content loaded');
        }, false );

        var x = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < 900000000; i++) {
            x++;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('timeout callback is running');
        }, 10);

        console.log('script finished');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>div content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output in Firefox console:

```
script is running
script finished
timeout callback is running
DOM content loaded
```

In Chrome console I get:

```
script is running
script finished
DOM content loaded
timeout callback is running
```

If I up the timeout to 100ms, I get Chrome's output in Firefox as well.

So, it seems that on Firefox the timeout callback "hijacks" the next frame, even though `DOMContentLoaded` is fired?
Or maybe it only fires after the callback returns?

[EDIT]

I've added a dynamically loaded script:

```
console.log('script is running');

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log('DOM content loaded');
}, false );

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout callback is running');
}, 1);

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'dynamic.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

var x = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    x++;
}

console.log('script finished');
```

dynamic.js:

```
(function() {
    console.log('dynamic script is running');

    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
        x++;
    }

    console.log('dynamic script finished');
})();
```

Now, Firefox console output is:

```
script is running
file:///foo/bar/dynamic.js
script finished
dynamic script is running
dynamic script finished
timeout callback is running
DOM content loaded
```

So Firefox even waits for dynamically loaded scripts to return before DOMContentLoaded callbacks run?

Answer (score 1):

Both are asynchronous, and they're not causally related. It's an expected [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) - sometimes the DOM is faster than 10ms and sometimes it's not.

And of course the results - if they are reproducible - might suggest that Chrome is faster than Firefox, or that Firefox just prioritises timeouts over DOM events. It doesn't matter. None of the implementations is "wrong".

Comment: I don't think there's a race condition here. I use a for loop to test what happens when the DOM takes some time to load. So the 'race' is rigged.
It seems that Firefox lets the timeout callback take it's place in the frame queue before the DOMContentLoaded event handler, while Chrome doesn't.

Comment: Your loop in the original test hardly made the DOM take more time to load (which is fired when the `</body>` is met), it was before the timeout as well. In your updated example, the timeout might fire during the loop, which completely explains the behaviour. And that dynamic script probably doesn't change too much, on your local testing system it just loads too fast to matter.